# Calling method from two different classes that have an implement

Tags: java

ok so I have to make a consoleprint interface class and two other classes that implement it

one class simply will let me print the text and the other u can see is string splitter. So far I have had problems with my tester

```
public interface ConsolePrint {

    public void printInfo(String infoToPrint);

}
```

---

```
public class SimplePrint implements ConsolePrint {

    public void printInfo (String infoToPrint) {
        printInfo("Heading this is not fancy");
    }
}
```

---

```
public class FancyPrint implements ConsolePrint {

    public void printInfo (String printInfo) {
        for (String splitter: printInfo.split("", 1)){
             System.out.println(splitter);
          }
    }
}
```

---

Heres the tester that I am getting problems from

```
import java.util.*;

public class ConsolePrintTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

    SimplePrint mySp = new SimplePrint();
    FancyPrint myFp = new FancyPrint();

    myFp.printInfo(); <-----error appearing here

}
```

---

Any help would be great thanks

Comment: `SimplePrint.printInfo` is infinite recursion.

Comment: _What_ error are you getting?

Answer (score 3):

You need to move your method call into your `main` method (or at least *some* method). Currently it's not in a method - only *declarations* (of fields, methods, nested types etc) can be at the top level of a class.

Additionally, you're not currently passing an argument to the `printInfo` method, but

So this would be fine:

```
public class ConsolePrintTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FancyPrint myFp = new FancyPrint();

        myFp.printInfo("some string");
    }
}
```

Note that:

- I've removed the import in the class as it was irrelevant
- I've removed the `mySp` declaration as that variable was never used
- You're not currently using the fact that the classes implement the interface. You might want to consider:

  ```
  ConsolePrint printer = new FancyPrint();
  printer.printInfo("some string");
  ```

As noted in comments, your `SimplePrint` implementation recurses unconditionally too, so that's the nest problem to fix.

Comment: thanks for your reply
I need to print the Heading is not fancy from the Simple Print class

public class ConsolePrintTest {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  SimplePrint mySp = new SimplePrint();
  FancyPrint myFp = new FancyPrint();

  mySp.printInfo();
  myFp.printInfo();
 }
}

Comment: @user3079838: I don't understand your comment at all, I'm afraid - especially as `printInfo` takes a string parameter, and the code in your comment doesn't give one. But don't focus on that part - focus on what was wrong from your previous code. If you have questions about *that*, ask in comments. If you face *new* problems, I suggest you ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Move the statement inside some method (`main` in your case):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    SimplePrint mySp = new SimplePrint();
    FancyPrint myFp = new FancyPrint();

    myFp.printInfo("Test String"); //No error now
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse an argument into your printInfo method as there is no method that take no arguments called printInfo.

Try:
myFP.printInfo("Hello world");

Additionally, you will get another error calling the SimplePrint implementation as it will never stop recursively calling the same function.

Comment: sorry I forgot to include mySp.printInfo();

Comment: this needs to print the text from the class "Heading this is not fancy"